# Control which rows a data table will calculate

Tags: excel

I have a 2-way data table in Excel (as in the option under "What-If Analysis"). There are 50 rows when analysing a 50 year deal, but only 4 rows when analysing a 4 year deal.

I only want to use one data table (of 50 rows) but I don't want it to calculate all of the values if it doesn't have to. e.g. if I have a five year deal I want the values in the first 5 rows to be calculated, but for the rest I would like it to display `0` or a blank.

Is there a way to do this without VBA?

(I was thinking with VBA I could create a whole new data table every time I run it, but would prefer not to as I am still developing structures.)

Comment: No, I'm not. Would you recommend one for this task?

Comment: That tag was meant to be data tables in excel (the option that comes under "What-if Analysis" on the Data tab)

Comment: Is the issue that you only want to *display* values in the relevant rows, for cosmetic purposes (which is easily handled via formulas) or that you only want to *run calculations* for relevant rows, for performance purposes?

Comment: For performance purposes, it is taking a long time to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that either your row labels will step consistently. Just blank out the years that are not required, when not required (rows 6 and upwards in your example for 5 years), and repopulate with series fill to suit.